# Install Ubuntu within Windows 7.0

Tags: installation

I've carefully followed instructions for downloading Ubuntu within Windows 7.0.

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/windows-installer

However, after the download, it gives me instructions for burning to disc.   I already have a disc (12.04.03) but I want to boot from C: drive

Comment: what exactly you want to do??

Answer (score 0):

see this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot
also this http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-with-windows
follow the steps here.